# How do I convert Q.defer() to Promise for instance variables?

Tags: javascript

I am currently looking to convert a library that uses Q.defer() for promise handling to use ES6 Promises. I understand the basics on how to convert Q.defer() to Promise, but every example I have ran into does not talk about the structure that I am running into where I need to convert class instance variables away from Q.defer() to Promises that do NOT resolve immediately. For example, take the following code.

```
import 'Q' from 'q';
class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.items = Q.defer();

    // This would then make a call to some backend service... setTimeout to simulate.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.items.resolve(['one', 'two', 'three']);
    }, 1000);
  }
  getItems() {
    return this.items.promise;
  }
}
```

I would like to use this class like the following.

```
let service = new Service();
service.getItems().then((items) => {
  console.log(items);
});
```

Currently, I am reading that you should use Promise.resolve() to create a similar structure, however, if I replace Q.defer() with Promise.resolve(), the promise resolves immediately with no items, which is not what I am wanting. Here is what I was thinking could be the replacement.

```
class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.items = Promise.resolve();

    // This would then make a call to some backend service... setTimeout to simulate.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.items.then(() => {
        return ['one', 'two', 'three'];
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work since the promise resolves immediately...

How do I convert the code above to use Promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `deferred` is not part of the [Promise specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) and a bit of an [anti-pattern](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html) so native Promises don't have the same concept.
This would work in native, but I'm not sure if you can wrap your methods like this.

```
class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.items = new Promise(deferred)
    function deferred(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(['one', 'two', 'three']);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to be able to call ```getItems``` immediately. I will update my original question to outline how I would like to use this class, which would not work for the example you gave. I do appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I just tried it, and it seems like this may work. I was under the impression that you needed to call ```Promise.resolve()``` in order to get the ```then``` methods to use. I will plug this into my library and then upvote if it works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can be used to solve this problem is to create a Polyfill of the Deferred class using the following code.

```
class Deferred {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject = reject;
    });
  }
}
```

And this can now be used like so...

```
class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.items = new Deferred();

    // This would then make a call to some backend service... setTimeout to simulate.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.items.resolve(['one', 'two', 'three']);
    }, 1000);
  }
  getItems() {
    return this.items.promise;
  }
}
```